# exporting superagent to a single js file with all modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, tizen, superagent

I have a sample code which uses superagent. But I need to run this on a platform with limited "require" support.
The platform is Tizen IDE for Samsung Gear S2 watch.

Since this platform supports require function only with requirejs and the format for includes change, I need minimum number of js files.
So I want a single file for superagent.

I found methods to export a single file superagent.js using browserify.
However, with that method I was not able to include modules in superagent (like qs, debug) 
How can I do that ?

For example, I want to access stringify function in qs module (stringify.js)
How can I create a single file for superagent including all modules and js files ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not import all the stuff into one file and then export all of it?

Comment: Put so the functions in a modules.exports object... Google that phrase

Comment: I  couldn't achieve that. there are too many files to include. would it be possiblke to create a single file using browserify ?